# how can I automate the web login part of a wifi connection in windows pc?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Each time I am connected to my home wifi network, I have to open my browser and enter the login details so that I get connected to the internet.

Off late, my login drops every 30 minutes and I lose connectivity. And now I cannot run my downloads overnight.

Is there anyway in which I can automate the login process? When

1. the system starts up?
2. Or a constant polling is done so as to find out whether internet connectivity is available? if not, then login.

There is an android app available with similar functionality- Wifi Web Login (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp&hl=en)

Is there any software for the same in windows? Or can I write scripts for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Wireless disconnects every 30 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/111561/wireless-disconnects-every-30-minutes) , you shouldn't be disconnected at regular intervals. Your problem may be caused by your router configuration.

If this can't be solved by a proper configuration, maybe you can find a script to connect to your exact router model. For example, putting some curl commands in a batch file to automate the login process.

You could put this script at the startup folder inside the start menu or add some timed ping checks, but I don't like this approach very much. You should put your efforts into finding what causes the regular logouts.